# PhoneGap Media API cannot overwrite recorded audio on iPhone device

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an audio file 'default.wav' in 'www/audio/' folder. In iOS simulator, I can record audio, overwrite the 'www/audio/default.wav', and play it. However, on the real device, the 'default.wav' cannot be overwritten. The device always play the unchanged audio file no matter how many times I record.
Could anyone please tell me how to save the new recorde audio or overwrite to 'default.wav' in 'www/audio/' folder on the device? I am using phonegap 1.3.0 on iPhone running iOS5.

```
function recordAudio() {
var src = "audio/default.wav";
mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
mediaRec.startRecord();
}

function stopRecordAudio(){
mediaRec.stopRecord();
mediaRec.release();
alert('stopRecordAudio');
}

function playAudio() {
var src = "audio/default.wav";
mediaPlay = new Media(src, onSuccessPlay, onErrorPlay);
mediaPlay.play();
}
```

Comment: Please check this sample http://html5help.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/phonegap-media-api/

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite files in the www directory. These are part of your application.

Comment: Could you point out any alternative method to save/retrieve my recorded audio on the iPhone device using Media API? Thanks!

Comment: You can continue to play the media from your www directory but you'll need to record to a different directory on your phone.